# What's the purpose of distinct in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today, I came across a query on W3Schools here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp which was written as below:

```
CREATE VIEW [Category Sales For 1997] AS
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName,Sum(ProductSales) AS CategorySales
FROM [Product Sales for 1997]
GROUP BY CategoryName
```

I am wondering what's the purpose of using `DISTINCT` in this query? The query has already `GROUPed BY` the result set, so there is no chances of same `CategoryName` after doing `GROUP BY` and before doing `SELECT`. Would this query behave differently if it did not use `DISTINCT`? I mean what would happen if it was written simply as this:

```
CREATE VIEW [Category Sales For 1997] AS
SELECT CategoryName,Sum(ProductSales) AS CategorySales
FROM [Product Sales for 1997]
GROUP BY CategoryName
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it. It's redundant and has no effect on the output.

Comment: I think so. although a bit strange!

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi I'd be surprised if the compiler did not optimize for this already.

Comment: Yeah! I made a table and did plan analysis. Looked like it did. So, there would be performance effect on the compiler only, but not on the output as you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly stated, GROUP BY already returns distinct values for the group-by-columns. As that one column is included in the select column list in your example, the DISTINCT does not provide any additional functionality.

Depending on the query (probably not in this case) an unnecessary DISTINCT can however hurt performance badly, so it is always a good idea to check if the DISTINCT is really necessary in any queries.

Comment: I was in doubt may be it is doing something I don't see. I liked your mentioning of the performance issue also. Thank you!

Comment: Runtime performance would not be affected; Although, it would affect compiler performance.

Comment: A DISTINCT requires SQL Server to execute a SORT operation, unless the data is sorted already or contains a column that is known to be unique. A SORT is one of the most expensive operations out there, so an unnecessary DISTINCT will affect runtime performance, not only compilation performance.